NextJS not listening Events on Laravel Echo
I created an api in Laravel and a front end in NextJS, in Laravel 11 I am using reverb as the documentation says:
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/reverb#main-content
I'm using Horizon to manage my queues, I created a Job to dispatch a new Event every time a change is made to an api function, this event must be sent to the websocket client that the change was made and a new one must be made request.
My Laravel channel in channels.php:
Broadcast::channel('order-list-updated', function ($user) {
    return true;
});

My laravel Event:
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrderListUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Indica se a lista de pedidos foi atualizada.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public bool $updated;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param bool $updated
     */
    public function __construct(bool $updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): Channel|array
    {
        return new Channel('order-list-updated');
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith(): array
    {
        return [
            'updated' => $this->updated,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Set the event name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function broadcastAs() {
        return 'OrderListUpdated';
    }
}


This is the CLI running Horizon, here is running the job, then the event with the listener:
  2024-05-15 13:53:30 App\Jobs\OrderUpdated .......................... RUNNING
  2024-05-15 13:53:30 App\Jobs\OrderUpdated ..................... 12.05ms DONE
  2024-05-15 13:53:30 App\Events\OrderListUpdated .................... RUNNING
  2024-05-15 13:53:30 App\Events\OrderListUpdated .............. 170.20ms DONE
  2024-05-15 13:53:30 App\Listeners\ProcessOrderListUpdate ........... RUNNING
  2024-05-15 13:53:30 App\Listeners\ProcessOrderListUpdate ....... 6.14ms DONE

When running php artisan reverb:start --debug it starts and connect with my NextJS frontend:
 Message Received ............................................................................................................. 645979221.436814049  
  
   1▕ { 
   2▕     "event": "pusher:subscribe", 
   3▕     "data": { 
   4▕         "auth": "", 
   5▕         "channel": "order-list-updated" 
   6▕     } 
   7▕ } 

  Message Handled .............................................................................................................. 645979221.436814049  


My browser in Network section:
network_browser
In NextJS, my echo.ts file to test the websocket locally:
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

const pusher = new Pusher('0f472f88d43afa26c12d', {
  cluster: 'sa1',
  forceTLS: false,
  wsPort: 8080,
  wsHost: 'localhost',
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
})

const echoConfig = {
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  client: pusher,
  cluster: 'sa1',
  forceTLS: false,
  wsPort: 8080,
  wsHost: 'localhost',
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
}

const echo = new Echo(echoConfig)

export default echo


How i'm listening the event in my page.tsx:
useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    const delay = 300

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const responses = await Promise.all([
          axios.post('/api/orders/index', {
            params: {
              order_type: 3,
              tenantToken: tenantToken,
              sanctumToken: sanctumToken,
            },
          }),
          axios.post('/api/orders/index', {
            params: {
              order_type: 1,
              tenantToken: tenantToken,
              sanctumToken: sanctumToken,
            },
          }),
          axios.post('/api/orders/index', {
            params: {
              order_type: 2,
              tenantToken: tenantToken,
              sanctumToken: sanctumToken,
            },
          }),
          axios.post('/api/orders/index', {
            params: {
              order_type: 4,
              tenantToken: tenantToken,
              sanctumToken: sanctumToken,
            },
          }),
        ])

        const dataToPrepare = responses[0].data.data
        const dataToPay = responses[1].data.data
        const dataToApprove = responses[2].data.data
        const dataToSend = responses[3].data.data

        setDataToPrepare(dataToPrepare)
        setDataToPay(dataToPay)
        setDataToApprove(dataToApprove)
        setDataToSend(dataToSend)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao buscar as encomendas:', error)
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false)
      }
    }

    const fetchDataAndSubscribe = async () => {
      await fetchData()

      const channel = echo.channel('order-list-updated')

      channel.listen('.OrderListUpdated', (event: any) => {
        console.log('Evento: ', event)
        fetchData()
      })
    }

    const timer = setTimeout(fetchDataAndSubscribe, delay)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [sanctumToken, tenantToken])

I changed it in dashboard.pusher for the client to receive responses:
client_event
I don't know why my websocket is not receiving any event.
Tryed changing the event name, the channel name and i didnt get it.

I think the problem is in the name of the event that you listen to in Echo, you have to remove the . from the name channel.listen('.OrderListUpdated', (event: any) should be channel.listen('OrderListUpdated', (event: any) !

i tried that but i couldn't receive anything and the documentation says that dot need to be there for some reason.
